# "Classic" lens on new "EVIL" camera body?

Tags: lens, canon, adapter

I have a Cannon Rebel XTi. I'm not sure if Cannon has released a series of EVIL (Electronic Viewfinder, Interchangeable Lens) cameras yet, but if not it's inevitable given their comeuppance in the market.

I am wondering if the lenses I own for my XTi will be interchangeable with an EVIL body, if I will need an adapter, or if I should be saving my pennies for new lenses?

Comment: Please read: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-we-allow-questions-about-unreleased-cameras

Comment: He does ask a useful question about lens potential though.

Comment: @fbreto, see also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/840/dx-or-fx-lenses. w.r.t. the closing, I think it's a perfectly reasonable planning question. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Canon was to release a mirrorless body and wished to support the EF/EF-S lenses on it, it would require an adapter because the registration distance will have changed. Basically, the gain with mirrorless is a thinner body, so the optical construction of current Canon lenses wouldn't work for it out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Until Canon release a mirrorless body, there will be no way of knowing if it will support EF or EF-S lenses.