# Would APS-C be better for shooting wildlife?

Tags: dslr, sensor, sensor-size, wildlife

Considering the magnification effect of APS-C sensors, they theoretically have to extend the zoom range of telephoto lenses. Accordingly, would it be wiser to use an APS-C camera for shooting wildlife instead of full frame, or this is just something that I only imagine and it'd be different in practice?

Comment: Same basic concept: [Are full-frame cameras bad for sports photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/are-full-frame-cameras-bad-for-sports-photography)

Comment: Then why not a Micro Four Thirds (crop factor 2x) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not necessarily.

The APS-C sensor merely crops the image that would have been captured on a full frame sensor, so you end up with what you'd get if you used a full frame and cropped in post (see: [Does my crop sensor camera actually turn my lenses into a longer focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/does-my-crop-sensor-camera-actually-turn-my-lenses-into-a-longer-focal-length) and [Is crop-factor a bad thing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/is-crop-factor-a-bad-thing))

But given a full-frame and a crop sensor of the same resolution, say 14MP, at least with the APS-C you'll have a 14MP end result. With full-frame, if you crop the image to match the APS-C image, you'd throw away pixels and end up with a 6MP image.

Comment: The critical thing here is that the lens has to be of sufficient quality.  I've done this test with my D7100 and D610 - both have the same image resolution (same MP) but the pixel density on the D7100 is naturally higher since the sensor is smaller.  If the lens is sharp enough then the D7100 full image will slightly outperform (in perceptual resolution/sharpness) the D610 cropped, simply because there is a higher pixel density in the cropped area.

Comment: @J... But that is only true when you are displaying at a large enough size that the difference in the number of pixels make a difference.

Answer (score 12):

Crop sensors are indeed used for wildlife to get more reach without sacrificing megapixels. And, you can get closer images without spending as much money. Sure, you could crop, but then your printing dimensions will be reduced. For display on the web, at 72dpi or so, it wouldn't matter if you cropped.

All that said, remember that to get the same image as a full frame sensor, you have to apply the crop factor to both the focal length **and** the aperture. Many photographers forget this, and think that their full-frame 200mm f2.8 lens will turn into a 300mm f2.8 on a crop sensor. Actually, you get the effect of a 300mm f4, instead.

Comment: Thank you actually stating the facts, including the f-stop issues.

Answer (score 6):

There can definitely be some benefit to be gained by using a crop sensor camera when longer focal length is desireable. It is one of the reasons compact "superzoom" cameras can give fields of view equivalent to 1000mm+ focal lengths on a full frame camera with a much smaller lens than would be required to get that same FoV using a full frame sensor camera.

If the pixel density is the same on a FF camera and an APS-C camera, then there would be little to no benefit (all other things being equal). But the pixel density is rarely the same. A typical APS-C camera might have a 20MP sensor that gives a pixel spacing of about 4 microns. A 22MP FF camera has a pixel spacing of 6.25 microns.

The crop factor of a particular sensor is based on *linear* measurements, but pixel density is measured in terms of pixels per area. This means the number of pixels on a FF sensor that fall within the space covered by a 1.5X APS-C sensor is not 1/1.5X, but 1/2.25X of the total number of pixels on the FF sensor. In the case of our typical 22MP FF camera, if we crop the image by 1.5X in the linear measurements we are only left with a pixel count of just under 10MP. In the case of cropping to match a 1.6X APS-C sensor it would only be about 8.6MP.

If 8-10MP is sufficient for your intended display size, then there will be very little difference between cropping the FF image or using the APS-C camera (all other things being equal). But if you need more than 8-10MP resolution for your intended display size, then the advantage of the APS-C body becomes obvious.

If you magnify the image projected by the lens, such as is the case with a teleconverter, you spread the light thinner and give up aperture in terms of the f-number used to calculate exposure. But if you increase magnification when printing or displaying the image you don't lose any aperture in terms of exposure. You do, however, lose performance in terms of perceived image noise when you magnify an image. Displaying the same image at different viewing sizes (magnifications) also affects the depth of field as perceived by the viewer at the same viewing distance.

Beyond the relative pixel densities, there is also the issue of comparing different generations of technology. A newer FF body might do better cropped to APS-C magnification compared to an older APS-C body. On the other hand, a newer APS-C body may do better when compared to a cropped image from an older FF body.

Also please note that when you crop a FF image to the same magnification as an APS-C sized image, you have just thrown away the extra light that the FF sensor collected to give it that one stop advantage in terms of noise.

Answer (score 4):

There's no universal answer.  Cameras are different, with differing resolutions, pixel pitch, and noise performance. A *newer* camera can trump a *bigger* camera.  Does the bigger one have bigger pixels, more pixels the same pitch, or something in between, which makes them harder to compare?

Also, you might be able to afford a much better lens (or only use the center part thus making a cheaper lens perform better) with a smaller sensor. Is the better optics a bigger or smaller effect than the difference in noise?

**Compare *actual cameras* and equipment that would make up the kit**, not one single property held by many cameras of different brands and tiers.  I've had a Sony alpha 6000 (crop) take a better picture than a Canon 5D (full) in the identical shot: the larger sensor gives a 1 stop advantage to low-light. The other camera had its own advantages. One stop due to one feature doesn't just trump everything else that's going on.

Comment: If you crop the FF image to the size of the APS-C image, you give up that stop of light advantage because you're throwing away roughly half the light the larger sensor collected.

Comment: "Identical shot" meant standing in the same place at the same time and filling the subject to the viewfinder to get the same picture. The lens focal length would hqce been different between the two cameras.

Comment: Then you're not, as the question states, "extending the zoom (sic) range of telephoto lenses." The question seems fairly clear to me to be comparing using the same focal length lens to either shoot with a FF camera and crop to the narrower FOV of an APS-C camera or shoot with an APS-C camera.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Given that he already has the longest lens he can get, the FF doesn't have its inherent advantage in play.

Answer (score 2):

Full frame cameras will give you better quality images especially in low light. However, they are bulky, heavy and expensive. And yes you do lose telephoto capability to a degree as the crop factor is not there. So you will need a bigger lens on a full frame to cover what you lost with a crop sensor camera. Which ofcourse will add to the weight. Some people are willing to live with this headache to get the best images possible. But others are not. Using cameras in real life in the field is always better teacher than theorizing about it. I currently use a crop sensor DSLR for nature photography and carry only 2 lightweight lenses. Since weight is an issue for me when i travel across the world. I have used all kinds of cameras on my travels and i am always looking to get the right balance between weight, bulk and performance.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers here compare the use of a crop-sensor camera with the
option of cropping in post. This raises the question of comparing either
megapixel counts or pixel densities, as discussed in all the answers.

However, all these answers fail to address a very essential issue:
**viewfinder magnification**. Crop-sensor cameras almost universally
have a larger viewfinder magnification than full frame cameras, which is
only natural given their smaller focusing screen. If you are going to
use only an APS-C (or smaller) area of your sensor anyway, an APS-C
camera will give you a better experience in terms of composing your shot
in the finder. With full frame you will have to compose on a smallish
partial viewfinder image.

Answer (score 0):

The short answers are:

1. If using a FF lens use a FF body. If using a APS-C lens use a APS-C body.
2. If you need to crop the FF image in post to get closer, then use an APS-C otherwise FF may be better after all.

Answer (score -1):

You could use APS-C camera to save some considerable weight, size or money. But if you are looking for the best image quality especially when the light is not plentiful, top of the line FF cameras will give you better chance compared to the same generation APS.

Comment: Look at dpreview: some APC sensor cameras have better low-light performance than some full-frame cameras.  In particular, see the notes for the Canon 7Dii.

Answer (score -1):

Full frame cameras offer better results in form of sharpness and noise, so you could use a full frame and crop it later in APS-C format.

Comment: When you crop and then enlarge to the same size, you effectively give up most of the advantage regarding both noise and sharpness. Those comparisons are only valid when images from both cameras are viewed with the *pixels* viewed at the same size (i.e. at 100% so that the magnification ratio is different for each image unless the pixel size is identical).