# Relationship between camera sensor size and lens focal length

Tags: lens, canon, focal-length

I am choosing a camera and lens.

I want to buy a Canon EOS 650D, as this camera seems to be a good point of entry into the world of SLR.

My question is in the following:

The EOS 650D has a cropped sensor, so as I understand if I use Canon 50mm f/1.8 lens, the behavior will be quite different on a smaller sensor in comparison to full-frame sensor.

What is the relation between cameras sensor size and lens focal length?

Comment: Hi Alex.  Basically with a smaller sensor, any lens is effectively 1.5-1.6 times what you'd get on a full frame.  So 50mm on a 650D is like a 75-80mm lens on a full frame camera. Have a look at these: 
[focal length and crop factor](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-the-difference-between-focal-length-and-crop-factor) and [Does my crop sensor camera actually turn my lenses into a longer focal length?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/does-my-crop-sensor-camera-actually-turn-my-lenses-into-a-longer-focal-length)

Comment: And this - [How can I get the same image with the same 50mm lens on both FF and APS-C?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11989/how-can-i-get-the-same-image-with-the-same-50mm-lens-on-both-ff-and-aps-c) - Those links should explain how it all works.  Basically a 35mm lens on a 650D is similar to a 50mm lens on full frame.  50mm is stil fine on a crop sensor, but if you're say indoors, you may find you don't have as much working room as you would with full frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 650D has a "crop factor" of 1.6 so a 50mm will have about the same field of view of 50*1.6=80mm on a full frame.

This does not change the lens's focal length (or any other optical property) you get a "zoom in" effect because you only looking at the center of the image projected by the lens, that center part of the image is exactly what you would see with a full frame camera in the same exact situation if you cropped the picture in post processing and kept only the center area.