# What Do I Gain from Moving to a Full-Frame DSLR?

Tags: nikon, sensor-size, full-frame, dx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do the differences between APS-C and full frame sensors matter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/why-do-the-differences-between-aps-c-and-full-frame-sensors-matter)

I'm on my 3rd Nikon DX DSLR (D70, D80 and now D7000).  I've enjoyed each camera and the advances brought by each model.  However, I'm getting the itch to consider going to a more pro-level kit, and I'm wondering what the advantages are to a full-frame sensor? Obviously, the 1.5X crop factor would be gone, but I'd like to hear from others who've made the transition, and whether they believe it was worth  it. I only have a few lenses (a kit, len, a prime and a 12-24 wide angle) so I'm not terribly vested in the DX format.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just gains... not comparing to smaller sensors.

(1) **Higher quality sensors, generally**. Because the photosites are not packed as close together on a full frame for a given pixel count, full frame sensors are less noisy

(2) **Typically the brands top end models are full frame**. so you typically get an entire suite of pluses such as build quality, weatherproofing, Viewfinder coverage (typically 100%), egonomics, etc. While this doesn't necessarily need to follow (best camera of brand = full frame), it is at the moment (Canon 1Ds, Nikon D3x, Leica M9 are all full frame)

(3) **1:1 comparisons with 35mm film cameras**... so a 50mm lens is 'normal' field of view.'

(4) if you like 'the wide look' (i.e. you use wide angle lenses) the **larger sensor uses a shorter lens to produce the same field of view** compared to crops. So a 21mm lens on FF is  pretty wide. In other words, a full frame wide lens typically has less distortion at a given field of view.

Comment: Great points.  I get really frustrated with my 50mm f/1.4 prime as it feels so crowded. I tend to shoot wider shots than zoomed, so that might be another important consideration. Thanks for your feedback!