# Best camera for beginner and knower?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, dslr, troubleshooting, learning

I'm a beginner photographer. I'm 13. I'm not thinking photography for a job, but for a VERY nice hody. My father also loves photography, he is an expert but he don't have time in the last years to improve his hobby... (Is a doctor)  So he has stayed a little bit far from the thing and he can't answer me all my questions. :)

So, my question is:

1) Best camera for an expert-beginner guy. (Around 350-400 
€ ).

2) Best sources to learn all important stuff in cameras and in their settings  .....etc.

Thanks!!

Comment: See also [What should I look for when shopping for my first mirrorless camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77805/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-mirrorless-camera)

Comment: See also [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first “serious” camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67987/what-do-i-need-to-consider-to-choose-between-dslr-mirrorless-or-a-compact-as-m)

Comment: Note that we don't do product recommendations per se (see [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for why not), but if the questions linked above, plus all the other very similar ones on the site, don't let you know how to make the decision for yourself, please do update this question with the *specific* things you're still having difficulty working out.

Comment: On the second part of your question — *this* site is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 2):

As your Dad is also a photographer talk with him about lens compatibility.  He may (or may not) want to let you borrow his lenses (they can be quite expensive).  He may be using something exotic that's not suited to your needs.

This is about the only special advice I'd give you.