# Relationship between the focal length and sensor size

Tags: sensor, focal-length

What is a relationship between the focal length of the lens and the sensor size to achieve the same image area ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry, but i really need help

Comment: @HenkHolterman
ok, approved your edition

Comment: see: [When do the differences between APS-C and full frame sensors matter, and why?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/when-do-the-differences-between-aps-c-and-full-frame-sensors-matter-and-why) and [What is crop factor and how does it relate to focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-crop-factor-and-how-does-it-relate-to-focal-length). Also possibly [Roger Cicala's lensrentals blog entry on the move to full frame](http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2010/07/the-full-frame-move).