# What is this 25-100mm lens with a 1 inch diameter mount?

Tags: lens, equipment-identification

I am trying to identify the brand/make/model of this lens. It has a thread mount, 24mm as I measured it. It has two zoom barrels and no manufacturer name stamp I can see, although it has 'lens made in Japan' and 'No. 105022' engraved on the mounting flange.

[image: lens1]
[image: lens2]

Any help id'ing this lens is appreciated.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the other end of the lens? Is there any writing or embossing on the lens cap? Is there filter diameter markings around the inside of the front of the lens?

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the info. I've used a magnifying glass, and there are no markings/engravings at all on the large end of the lens, and no lens cap except for a Sony lens cap that someone put on it, but it's not even the right size. Looks like it would be a 75mm filter on the end. Thanks a lot for the quick response, I was guessing it was a Tamron or Soligor or other type brand. I don't know if anyone can use it.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. The Tamron brand and lens information engraving is clearly visible in the lookalike image in my answer, so I'm surprised there's nothing on your lens. Wonder if it's a rebrand, or perhaps repaired with non-branded parts, or... ? Looks like you have a mystery on your hands.

Comment: From what I can tell, someone removed the inner ring with the Tamron name and lens info. There are what appear to be marks and scratches in the area where that ring with the logo would be, so I'm guessing it was removed for some strange reason.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a [C-mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mount) lens, probably for video cameras, such as for 8mm or 16mm video. From the information given, there is no way to tell what the intended camera format was.

Based on the alternating silver/black pattern on the focus, aperture, and zoom rings, this appears to an older Tamron lens. A couple images from a lens that looks like it matches its exact appearance shows up in Google, referring to a Yahoo auction page that no longer exists, but was titled "not for sale TAMRON TV ZOOM f=25-100mm 1:1.8 C mount lens".

[image: Tamron TV zoom 1] [image: Tamron TV zoom 2]
<sup>Tamron TV zoom 25-100mm ƒ/1.8 C-mount lens. Retrieved from Google Image cache under fair use for educational purposes</sup>

The C-mount has a 1-inch (25.4mm) diameter. As noted in the C-mount Wikipedia article linked above, just knowing that the lens is C-mount does not tell you a lot. It doesn't tell you what the lens was intended to be mounted on. Depending on the size of the image circle cast by the lens, it might be incompatible with larger (at the time) format video. For instance, if the lens was intended to be used with 8mm video, then its image circle will visibly crop if mounted on a 16mm format camera. See the following article for a similar question about lenses on different sized imaging sensors: [When do the differences between APS-C and full frame sensors matter, and why?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/when-do-the-differences-between-aps-c-and-full-frame-sensors-matter-and-why/)

Answer (score 1):

Tamron 1 inch sensor lens. This should cover most of the m4/3 sensor. It is quite old as the 'zebra' colour scheme suggests. The first zooms were 2x, then 3x then 4x then 5 and 6x. 1.8 is quite fast, many are 2.8 or 2.5 of that era. Quite filmic, so no need for mist filters.

It covers more than a 16mm and possibly a Super16mm lens. Very heavy and may not suit the tiny cameras without support. Should be perfect for a BMPCC 1080P and similar small sensor cameras.

I don't have one in my collection.