# Why move from Nikon DX to FX

Tags: nikon

I'm just getting into Real Estate photography, I'm currently using a D3100 that seems to work well for me so far. I have been told I really need to move up to a FX camera body. Ok I understand the sensor size, but really what am would I gain? It is a pretty good chunk of money a good FX body.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, this has been discussed, but relevant answer is [pretty deep in there](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/3990/38691).

I think for real estate, when you want rooms and house to look As Big As Possible, Full-Frame's benefit is a possibility of using wider lenses. For example, [Nikon's 14mm lens](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/1428.htm) has a field of view that would require non-existing 9.3mm lens to reproduce on crop sensor (d3100)

Canon has full-frame [11mm lens](http://www.kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/11-24mm.htm) that produces same field of view as non-existing 6.9mm lens on crop sensor

PS: as far as I know, widest crop lens for Canon or Nikon is [Sigma 8-16mm zoom](http://www.kenrockwell.com/sigma/8-16mm.htm), that is equivalent to 12-24mm on full-frame. You might want to give it a try.

PPS: Here we talk only about [rectilinear lenses, not fisheye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_lens) that can come in wider focal lengths but will create great distortion to the image (mostly for artistic purposes)